# Writing sums with step-size unequal to 1.

Tags: reference-request, summation, notation

Assume that you have $\delta$ is a positive number. Real numbers $b\ge a$, and $b-a=K\delta$, K is a natural number.

I know we can write $\sum\limits_{i=0}^K f(a+i\delta)$, for $f(a)+f(a+\delta)+\ldots f(b)$.

But is there another way to do this so we do not have to know the number $K$? Is there a standard way to write $\sum\limits_{t=a}^bf(t)$. But where we increase by $\delta$ not $1$?

Comment: If you know $a$, $b$, and $\delta$ then you also know $K$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, it is no problem mathematically, I just want a compact and nice way to write it. If you have to introduce K it looks more messy, so I am wondering if there is a standard way to get around it.

Comment: AFAIK there is none.